Как сконвертировать int64_t в строку формата "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"?
Моя проблема в том, что time_t - 32бит, и скоро с ним уже сложно будет работать ( проблема 2038 года )
Поэтому хочу расширить time_t в int64_t.
И функции которые работали с time_t мне теперь не подойдут видимо
Например не подойдет уже такая конвертация в tm, потому что функция принимает std::time_t, который 32бита
 ::tm tmTime{};
 ::tm * ptm = boost::date_time::c_time::localtime( &t, &tmTime );


Стандарт не специфицирует физический тип time_t, у большинства компиляторов он либо уже синоним для int64_t, либо это можно указать в параметрах компиляции.

наврятли я смогу указать параметры компиляции для этого типа. 32бит. все что имею

Года-минуты-часы? Года-месяцы-часы?

@AlexeyTen, не важно какой формат
